# Why is there a need to add the complex conjugate in the tight binding hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, tight-binding

So we start with the following hamiltonian describing non-interacting free fermions:

> $$ \hat{H}_{\text{free}}
>  = \sum_{i,j,\sigma}\tilde{t}_{ij} \hat{c}_{i\sigma}^\dagger\hat{c}_{j\sigma}.$$

Then we make the following approximation of nearest neighbors:

> $$t_{ij}=\begin{cases}
>  -t, & \text{$i$ and $j$ are nearest neighbors} \\
>  0,  & \text{otherwise}
>  \end{cases}, $$
>   so we obtain the *tight-binding Hamiltonian*
>   $$ \hat{H}_{\text{tb}}
>  =-t \sum_{\langle ij\rangle,\sigma} (\hat{c}_{i\sigma}^\dagger\hat{c}_{j\sigma}
>  +\hat{c}_{j\sigma}^\dagger\hat{c}_{i\sigma}).
>  \tag{Bravais lattice}$$

I don't get why we need to add the complex conjugate. If I'm summing over all nearest neighbors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $<ij>$ means the bond between site $i$ and site $j$. Thus $\sum_{<ij>}$  sums over each bond once. Then one can hop from $i$ to $j$ or from $j$ to $i$.  No double counting therefore.

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense :)